# Slack: how to limit the multiple "notifications per second" rate from an active chat?

Tags: notifications, slack

I want to avoid getting a ding for every single message that is entered in a new group chat where everyone is typing at once.

**It should be illegal for Slack to send you a ding more often than once a minute from the same source.**

If you're in the middle of anything crucial, and someone starts a group chat with 10 employees, and they all furiously type at the same time, your phone / devices all start dinging and buzzing many times a second forever forever forever until you find the preferences to silence it. Except I don't even want to silence new messags, I just want to rate-limit the dings!

This behaviour should be replaced by just one ding/timeperiod. One new group chat = one event = one ding per x minutes. Regardless of how many new messages are in that chat. Wtf what kind of inexplicable dystopian horror monsters are working at Slack?

Comment: This is really just a rant.  You probably need to enter feedback to Slack.

Comment: I am (mostly) looking for missed settings, or hacks or slack apps or any "mods" I can do :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 90% of it is ranting. Remove the unnecessary complaining parts if you're really looking for a solution. It's not a part of Slack by default IIRC, but maybe it's achievable with some 3rd party application, better to ask here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered